# Ansible: Failed to connect to the host via ssh; unknown key

Tags: ssh, ansible

I encountered an issue while connecting SSH host on Ansible. The error message is:

```
UNREACHABLE! => {
  "changed": false,
  "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: vdollar_percent_expand: unknown key %t\r\npercent_expand failed",
  "unreachable": true
}
```

Comment: This is not an SSH error. What are you using that connects via SSH? And what version of it? The error indicates that `%t` is unknown.

Comment: Using Linux connection, CentOS default SSH tool.

Comment: That does not like an error message from an SSH client. It looks like ansible or something similar.

Comment: Yes, sorry! I replied to the wrong question just now. I am using Ansible for connectivity testing; the connectivity tests for CentOS and Windows Server 2019 are normal, but when testing the connectivity of the OpenCloudOS Server 9 system's cloud server, I encountered the error mentioned above. The connection is normal when using Xshell.

Comment: Then please provide your Ansible connection settings.